# What i need to do to backup and secure my mobile data before sending it to repair

Tags: iphone, ios, security, repair

I have iPhone 11 and its screen was broken, so I will send it to an authorized reseller for Apple. but before doing so I will remove all the data I have these data include; photos, videos, apps (mail app, WhatsApp, and other apps).

How I can securely remove the data inside my phone, so it can not be recovered when I send it to the technician?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We strongly prefer one question per question. How you back up the device doesn’t change with repair. Let’s get you to ask that question if you can’t find a question here that explains how to back up your iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple gives instructions on what to do before a repair, bit it should really just be this article.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201351

I prefer that checklist since it talks about Apple Watch and health data backup. You can not get that data back, so by following that before you sanitize your device, it’s protected. Ship the device insured since you can’t have Activation Lock enabled and follow the process.